# Mysql showing all not just selected

Tags: mysql, forms, select

Im trying to make a test form (wizard) and on each step (tab) I have all the rows from $step query instead of just the ones that I need.
The tables in db looks something like this

```
//main_steps
id_main_steps = 1...40
step_number = 5.[1..40]

//vpf_steps
step = 5.[1..40].[1..x]

//code
$main = mysql_query("select * from main_steps")or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($main)){
 echo "<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"tab5".$row1['id_main_steps']."\">".$row1['step_number']."-".$row1['step_measurement']."</div>";
 $step = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vpf_steps where step like '".$row1['step_number'].".%'")or die(mysql_error());
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($step)){
  echo "
    <div class=\"form-group\">
     <div class=\"row\">
      <div class=\"col-md-2\">".$row2['step']."</div>
      <div class=\"col-md-4\">".$row2['measurement']."</div>
      <div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"".$row2['input_type']."\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"".$row2['step']."\"></div>
    </div>
   </div>";
 }
}
```

UPDATE
Table structure
main steps

```
id_main_steps | step_number | step_measurement
      1       |      5.01   |    main_step1
      2       |      5.02   |    main_step2
....
```

vpf_steps

```
id_vpf_steps |   step      | measurement
       1     | 5.01.01     |    step1_1
       2     | 5.01.02     |    step1_2
       3     | 5.01.03     |    step1_3
       4     | 5.02.01     |    step2_1
       5     | 5.02.01     |    step2_2
....
```

And the output should be something like this

```
on tab1
5.01 main_step1
   5.01.01 step1_1
   5.01.02 step1_2
   5.01.03 step2_3

on tab2
5.02 main_step2
   5.02.01 step2_1
   5.02.01 step2_1
```

but what I get is

```
on tab1
5.01 main_step1
   5.01.01 step1_1
   5.01.02 step1_2
   5.01.03 step2_3
   5.02.01 step2_1
   5.02.01 step2_1


on tab2
   5.01.01 step1_1
   5.01.02 step1_2
   5.01.03 step2_3
5.02 main_step2
   5.02.01 step2_1
   5.02.01 step2_1
```

Comment: Pls provide the table structures, some sample data, and expected output!

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This fixes everything

```
            $main = mysql_query("select * from main_steps")or die(mysql_error());
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($main)){
                echo "<div class=\"tab-pane\" id=\"tab5".$row1['id_main_steps']."\">".$row1['step_number']."-".$row1['step_measurement']."";
                $step = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vpf_steps where step like '".$row1['step_number'].".%'")or die(mysql_error());
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($step)){
                    echo "
                        <div class=\"form-group\">
                            <div class=\"row\">
                                <div class=\"col-md-2\">".$row2['step']."</div>
                                <div class=\"col-md-4\">".$row2['measurement']."</div>
                                <div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"".$row2['input_type']."\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"".$row2['step']."\"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
            }
```